# Concat without blank in C# Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, concatenation

I am concatenating different Address fields in my LINQ Query to get one Address with merge.

```
public static IList GetOfferList()
{
    using (var objEntity = new dbContext())
    {
      string[] ListCategoryID = CategoryID.Split(',');
      return (from TBL.OfferMaster
              select new
              {
                PrimaryID = OM.OfferID,
                Address =  OM.StreetAddress + " ," + OM.City + " ," + OM.State + " ," + OM.Country + " ," + OM.ZipCode,
              }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Currently i get fields like

```
Address=Fákafen 11 ,Reykjavik , ,Iceland ,108,
```

Or

```
Address: " , , , ,",;
```

I want

```
Address=Fákafen 11 ,Reykjavik ,Iceland ,108
```

means blank fields not required.

Comment: Add a check of `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: I assume this is LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Use either IsNullOrEmpty() or check the string length (str.length != 0).  I would suggest go with IsNullOrEmpty() as suggested by Shaunak.

Comment: I'm just wondering why that `ListCategoryID` split code is there. The whole thing is never used...

Comment: Personally I recommend just building a `GetAddressString(OM)` function, instead of polluting this query block with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this.

```
Address = string.Join(" ," (new string[] {OM.StreetAddress, OM.City, OM.State,  OM.Country, OM.ZipCode})
                          .Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
```

Comment: Might want to put the space _after_ the comma. It's the more common use ;)

Comment: Ideally yes, you are correct. OP in the example shown space before `,`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var results = (from TBL.OfferMaster
            select new
            {
                PrimaryID = OM.OfferID,
                Address = String.Join(", ", (new string[] { OM.StreetAddress, OM.City, OM.State, OM.Country, OM.ZipCode })
                                                .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))),
            }).ToList();
```